# Using beautiful soup to scrape HTML, I can't get URL's from the website

Tags: html, parsing, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get("https://news.ycombinator.com/")
yc_webpage = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(yc_webpage, 'html.parser')

article_tag = soup.find(class_='titleline')
article_text = article_tag.get_text()
print(article_text)

article_score_tag = soup.find(class_='score')
article_score_text = article_score_tag.get_text()
print(article_score_text)

article_url_tag = soup.find(class_='titleline', name='span')
print(article_url_tag.get('href'))
```

So I'm able to get the article text and upvote values for the particular article however I'm struggling to get the url link from the tag. Does anyone have any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix this error during scraping using BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75008206/how-to-fix-this-error-during-scraping-using-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 0):

Try to search for `<a>` tag inside `article_url_tag`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://news.ycombinator.com/")
yc_webpage = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(yc_webpage, "html.parser")
article_tag = soup.find(class_="titleline")
article_text = article_tag.get_text()
print(article_text)
article_score_tag = soup.find(class_="score")
article_score_text = article_score_tag.get_text()
print(article_score_text)
article_url_tag = soup.find(class_="titleline", name="span")
print(article_url_tag.a.get("href"))  # <-- put .a here
```

Prints:

```
Normalization of Deviance (2015) (danluu.com)
68 points
https://danluu.com/wat/
```