# How to scrape website and avoid empty list as result?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to build a web scraper in Python, but I have a problem.

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


def get_articles():
    '''Gets the title and description of the first 10 articles on Hacker News.'''
    response = requests.get("https://news.ycombinator.com/")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    articles = soup.find_all("a", class_="storylink")
    return [{"title": article.text, "description": article["href"]} for article in articles[:10]]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    articles = get_articles()
    print(articles)
    # df = pd.DataFrame(articles)
    # print(df)
    # df.to_csv("hacker_news_articles.csv")
```

The code should give me a `list` of the titles and descriptions of the first 10 articles on Hacker News. However, it just returns an empty `list`.

What my code returns:
[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

I changed the parameters your passing to the .find_all() method. Then I need to call an extra .find() method to get the title and href of the articles. It looks like this produces the correct output.

My final function looks like this:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

def get_articles(): 
    '''Gets the title and description of the first 10 articles on Hacker News.''' 
    response = requests.get("https://news.ycombinator.com/") 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser") 
    articles = soup.find_all("span", class_="titleline") 

    data = []
    for article in articles[:10]:
        articleDetails = {}
        articleDetails['title'] = article.find('a').text
        articleDetails['href'] = article.find('a')['href']
        data.append(articleDetails)

    return data

print(get_articles())
```

Answer (score 0):

[BeautifulSoup webscraping find_all( ): finding exact match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726860/beautifulsoup-webscraping-find-all-finding-exact-match)

> In BeautifulSoup 4, the class attribute (and several other attributes, such as accesskey and the headers attribute on table cell elements) is treated as a set; you match against individual elements listed in the attribute. This follows the HTML standard. As such, you cannot limit the search to just one class. You'll have to use a custom function here to match against the class instead.

`tag.attrs` returns all the attributes of the tag and `tag.attrs['class']` returns a list of all the class names so we check if the particular class ('hnuser' in the example below) is in it.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

def get_articles():
    response = requests.get("https://news.ycombinator.com/")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    articles = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'a' and tag.has_attr('class') and 'hnuser' in tag.attrs['class'])
    return [ {"title": article. text, "description": article["href"]} for article in articles[:10]]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    articles = get_articles()
    print(articles)
```

Answer (score 0):

The empty `list` indicates that the element search did not find anything with your search criterion `.find_all("a", class_="storylink")`, so you should check it.

Try to select your elements correct by class `titleline` and may more specific for example with [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors).

```
soup.select('td.titleline a')
```

or just

```
soup.select('.titleline a')
```

*If you need to extract also the votes, ... check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75008462/14460824)*

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


def get_articles():
    '''Gets the title and description of the first 10 articles on Hacker News.'''
    response = requests.get("https://news.ycombinator.com/")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

    return [
        {
            'title':article.get_text(),
            'url':article.get('href')
        } for article in soup.select('.titleline a')[:10]
    ]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    articles = get_articles()
pd.DataFrame(articles)
```

###### Output

|  | title | url |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | I'm OK, the bull is dead (2004) | https://www.computerworld.com/article/2565077/i-m-ok--the-bull-is-dead.html |
| 1 | Show HN: Pip Imports in Deno | https://github.com/denosaurs/deno_python |
| 2 | What is gained and lost with 63-bit integers? (2014) | https://blog.janestreet.com/what-is-gained-and-lost-with-63-bit-integers/ |
| 3 | Fooocus: OSS for image generation by ControlNet author | https://github.com/lllyasviel/Fooocus |
| 4 | 80% of bosses say they regret earlier return-to-office plans | https://www.cnbc.com/2023/08/11/80percent-of-bosses-say-they-regret-earlier-return-to-office-plans.html |
| 5 | Wendelstein 7-X: Gigajoule energy turnover generated for eight minutes | https://www.ipp.mpg.de/5322229/01_23 |
| 6 | Special Relativity: Lorentz Transformations (2018) [video] | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rh0pYtQG5wI |
| 7 | We need scientific dissidents | https://www.chronicle.com/article/we-need-scientific-dissidents-now-more-than-ever |
| 8 | Zero Motorcycles makes its service manuals free | https://www.hagerty.com/media/maintenance-and-tech/zero-motorcycles-steps-up-and-makes-its-service-manuals-free/ |
| 9 | Do we really need a specialized vector database? | https://modelz.ai/blog/pgvector |